# How do I concatenate all the files in a given directory in order of date, where I want the newest file on top?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cat

And with the oldest file on bottom?

Also, if I do this, is it also possible to strip out the redundant headers contained within each HTML file? I'm seeing myself concatenate a lot of HTML files up, and it would be nice to reduce the file size of the ultimate file a bit.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To concatenate files you use

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ...
```

To get a list of quoted filenames sorted by time, newest first, you use

```
ls -t
```

Putting it all together,

```
cat $(ls -t) > outputfile
```

You might want to give some arguments to `ls` (eg, `*.html`).

But if you have filenames with spaces in them, this will not work. `My file.html` will be assumed to be two filenames: `My` and `file.html`. You can make `ls` quote the filenames, and then use `xargs`, who understands the quoting, to pass the arguments to `cat`.

```
ls -tQ | xargs cat
```

As for your second question, filtering out parts of files isn't difficult, but it depends on what exactly you want to strip out. What are the “redundant headers”?

Comment: This isn't working on my debian system... I have to use `cat $(ls -t) > outputfile`, otherwise `cat` rejects the quoted file names

Comment: My mistake. I always get caught on these things. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh - by redundant headers I mean things that are normally put in some header.php/footer.php file, but which are saved separately when saved to HTML (and can really increase the file size when you mass-download PHP pages).

Comment: `cat $(ls -t)` is also vulnerable to filename expansion. If there's a filename with an `*`, or `?`, or a bracket expression (e.g. `file-[old].html`); and if the filename interpreted as a pattern matches other filenames; the approach will produce an incorrect list. `set -f` would address this deficiency.

Comment: `ls -Q` may produce output which is not suitable for `xargs`. For example, `"foo"` becomes `"\"foo\""`, but xargs does not understand escaped double quotes within double quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of listing files in an order other than lexicographic is with zsh [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Without zsh, you can use `ls`, but [parsing the output of `ls` is fraught with dangers](http://mywiki.wooledge.com/ParsingLs).

```
cat *(om)
```

If you want to strip some lines, use sed or awk or perl. For example, to take the `<head>` from the first file and combine the `<body>` parts from the other files, assuming that the `<body>` and `</body>` tags are alone on a line in every file:

```
{
  sed -e '/<\/body>/ q' *.html(om[2])
  sed -e '1,/<body>/ d' -e '/<\/body>/,$ d' *.html(om[3,-1])
  echo '</body>'
  echo '</html>'
} >concatenated.html
```

Explanation:

- First, `concatenated.html` is created. It is therefore the youngest `*.html` file (assuming no file has a date in the future.
- Then copy from the second-youngest `*.html` file, but quit at the `</body>` line.
- Then copy from the other files, but skip everything down to the `<body>` line and starting with the `</body>` line.
- Finally produce the last closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by @angus is good but will have issues if there are directories in the folder this will fix it.

`cat $(ls -tpa | grep -v / )`

Comment: Caveat: This answer is also vulnerable to pathname expansion, as explained in my comment to angus' answer.

Comment: Unless cat's exit status is tested, a directory argument should be inconsequential. cat will simply emit a message to stderr and proceed to the next argument.